# SqlException (0x80131904): All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

Query:

```
USE [IEC]
GO

ALTER VIEW [dbo].[V_AllOA]
AS
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderId) OAId,
           *
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM BranchOrder
        WHERE Flag IN (1, 2)
            UNION
        SELECT *
        FROM BranchOrder12_13
        WHERE flag IN (1, 2)
            UNION
        SELECT *
        FROM BranchOrder11_12
        WHERE flag IN (1, 2)
    ) a

GO
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome. What's your question? And please show the code as well.

Comment: The error message tells you what exactly to look for.

Comment: tell me how can i solve this

Comment: @AnkitSharma - don't use wildchar * for selecting columns. use columnnames instead: SELECT col1, col2, col3

Comment: okay ...wait i am trying

Comment: wow ....bro you are great..... !!! worked for me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using union, you must make sure all the columns, including their **ORDER** and **TYPE** are the same.

for example: table1

```
ID,  NAME   , LASTNAME
 1  'john'     'smith'
```

table2 -

```
ID , NAME , MIDDLENAME , LASTNAME
 4  'john'    'bing'      'smith'
```

On the example above, both table can't be union using select * since they have different number of columns.

In that case, you can specify the **same** columns that appears on both table in your select statement like this:

```
SELECT ID,NAME,LASTNAME from table1
UNION
SELECT ID,NAME,LASTNAME from table2
```

This is a correct query.

```
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE2
```

This is not a correct query.

Answer (score 2):

Your tables BranchOrder, BranchOrder12_13, BranchOrder11_12 have different number of columns. They must all have exact number of columns and they must be in the same order - I mean if first column in first table is integer, the first column in other tables must be integer as well.